Derivation of ODE for $c_n(t)$ in Time-dependent Perturbation Theory
I'm going through the notes on Time-dependent perturbation theory from MIT OCW and want to make sure I understand how we're going from the first equality to the second in the picture attached below:
Here, $H^{(0)}$ is a known time-independent hamiltonian and $\delta H(t)$ is a time-dependent perturbation.

My reasoning is that we can write
$$ \langle m | \exp \left( \frac{iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) \delta H(t) \exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) |n \rangle =  \left( \exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) | m \rangle \right)^{\dagger} \delta H(t) \left( \exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) | n \rangle \right) $$
and then using the expansion of the exponential,
$$ \exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) | n \rangle = \left( \mathbb{1} + \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} + \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right)^2 + \cdots  \right)|n\rangle $$
and applying $H^{(0)}$ $k$-times on $|n\rangle$ gives $(E_n)^k |n\rangle$ so overall, we have
$$  \exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right) | n \rangle = \left( \mathbb{1} + \frac{-iE_nt}{\hbar} + \left( \frac{-iE_nt}{\hbar} \right)^2 + \cdots  \right)|n\rangle = \exp \left( \frac{-iE_nt}{\hbar} \right) |n \rangle $$
The same argument holds for $\exp \left( \frac{-iH^{(0)}t}{\hbar} \right)|m\rangle$, whose adjoint we take. So, we end up with the desired expression.
I want to ask, Is this correct? And have I missed out on anything subtle?

Don't use images/screenshots for equations (or text). Use MathJax, i.e. type the relevant passage.

The far RHS of your last equation has the hamiltonian in it, so it is literally identical to the far LHS of your last equation. Did you mean to write it that way, or did you mean to write $e^{\frac{-iE_nt}{\hbar}}|n\rangle$?

Ah, yeah I meant to write $\exp(\frac{-iE_nt}{\hbar})|n\rangle$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Your reasoning is correct. To summarize, one way of thinking about the exponential of an operator is in terms of a sum of powers of that operator (with some constant coefficients). You know how powers of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$ act on its eigenstates $\lvert n \rangle$. Hence, you know how the exponential of $H_0$ acts on its eigenstates. The result is particularly simple
$$e^{-iH_0t/\hbar} \lvert n \rangle = e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\lvert n\rangle.$$
By the reasoning above, this relationship holds true for any operator $O$ and its eigenstates $\lvert \lambda_n \rangle$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_n$
$$e^{-iO} \lvert \lambda_n \rangle = e^{-i\lambda_n}\lvert \lambda_n\rangle.$$
